# Windows 8 Store application XAML ListView Scroll Changed Event

Tags: xaml, listview, scroll

I want to detect ListView Scroll Changed Event in Windows 8 Store application is there any way ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try event [DragLeave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.dragleave.aspx)?

I found this discussion [WinRT XAML: Automatically Scrolling ListView and Detection](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/winrt-xaml-automatically). Hope it helps you ;)